# GCP: How to do DNS Peering between 2 VPCs that use VPC Peering in the same project

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, internal-dns, google-cloud-dns

In Google Cloud Platform, how do I set up private DNS Peering between two VPCs that are connected with VPC Peering, but reside in the same project?

I have one project `my-project` and two VPC networks: `blue` and `pink`. The two VPCs are peered. I want VMs on `blue` to be able to reach VMs on `pink` by their internal name, such as `pink-vm.us-west1-b.c.my-project.internal`, and vice versa.

If I set up 1 private DNS Peering zone for `my-project.internal` on the `pink` network and peer it to the `blue` network, I can reach instances on `blue` by name from `pink`. Success! But I still cannot reach instances on `pink` from `blue`.

Now, if I set up a second DNS Peering zone on the blue network (also set to `my-project.internal`), nothing works anymore. I get the following error when I try to ping:

```
me@blue-vm$ ping pink-vm.us-west1-b.c.my-project.internal
ping: pink-vm.us-west1-b.c.my-project.internal: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

It seems like the 2 reciprocal DNS Peering zones can't work together. They are peering `blue` to `pink` and `pink` to `blue` each under the domain `my-project.internal`. How can I make it so that my peered VPCs in the same project can resolve names in each other's network?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear, DNS peering and VPC network peering are different services. DNS peering can be used in conjunction with VPC network peering, but VPC network peering is not required for DNS peering.

DNS peering is a one-way relationship. That is why DNS queries don’t work when you add the second DNS peering `blue` -> `pink`.
DNS peering doesn’t support bi-directional DNS queries as stated on the public documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#dns_peering_limitations

Comment: The trick here is that the 2 VPCs are in the _same_ project. If they were in different projects, I could set up two DNS Peering connections and all the .internal names would resolve for both networks. I'm asking how (or whether) I can peer these .internal names for two VPCs in the same project.

Comment: That seems not to be possible, documentation explains clearly that is not possible to resolve internal DNS queries with other VPC networks, even if they are in the same project.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#about_internal_dns